# What's the difference between a sum and a direct sum for a chain complex?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, notation, definition, direct-sum

> **SUM:**  Let $S_*'$ and $S_*''$ be subcomplexes of $S_*$. Then
> $S_*'+S_*''$ is the subcomplex of $S_*$ whose $n$th term is $S_*'+S_*''$.
>
> **DIRECT SUM**: Let $\{(S_*^{\lambda}, \partial^{\lambda}) : \lambda \in \Gamma\} $ be a family of complexes.  Their direct sum is the complex
> $$... \rightarrow \sum_{\lambda} S_{n+1}^{\lambda} \rightarrow ^{\partial_{n+1}}\sum_{\lambda} S_{n}^{\lambda} \rightarrow ^{\partial_{n}} \sum_{\lambda} S_{n-1}^{\lambda} \rightarrow \dots$$ where $\partial_n = \sum_{\lambda} \partial_n^{\lambda}: \sum_{\lambda}s_n^{\lambda} \mapsto \sum_{\lambda} \partial_n^{\lambda}(s_n^{\lambda})$ for $s_n^{\lambda} \in S_n^{\lambda}$.

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between these two definitions.

For a sum, I see that $S_*' + S_*''$ means the indirect product of the two subgroups of $S_*$, as in $S_*'+S_*''=\{x+y : x \in S_*' \text{ and } y \in S_*''\}$.

But what does the summation notation mean when the groups involved aren't subgroups of a larger group?  If $S_n(X)$ and $S_n(Y)$ are members of the family, what does $S_n(X) + S_n(Y)$ mean if they're different groups?  And how would you define $x + y$ as a sum of elements from this group?

Comment: If you don't have an ambient group/chain complex, the sum always denotes the direct sum.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the term ambient group/chain complex.  But assuming there isn't one here, how would you still define a direct sum of two different groups?  What's $S_n(X) + S_n(Y)$?  Every definition of direct sum (indirect product) I'm aware of involves the groups being subgroups of a larger group.

Comment: Unless you think this definition should have the phrase "family of complexes" replaced with  "family of **subcomplexes**"?  Thereby following the definition of direct sum?

Comment: If you have a large group or chain complex, and a subgroup resp. subcomplex, the large thing is the ambient thing. What the smaller thing is embedded in. The direct sum of $S_n(X)$ and $S_n(Y)$ is $S_n(X) \oplus S_n(Y)$, the standard concrete realisation of that is the set of pairs $\{(a,b) : a \in S_n(X), b \in S_n(Y)\}$, with componentwise operations. For $\bigoplus S_n^{\lambda}$, the elements are the "sequences" with only finitely many nonzero terms. (Since we're abelian, the coproduct of non-abelian groups is far less nice.)

Comment: So you're saying the direct sum used here is not an indirect product but a direct product?  As an example to make sure I understand the the differences:  $S_n(X) = \sum _{b \in B} \langle b \rangle$ where $B$ is the basis and $\sum$ means internal direct product, and if $S_n(X)$ and $S_n(Y)$ are not subgroups of a larger group then $S_n(X) + S_n(Y) $ means external direct product?

Comment: Where is this definition from?  Normally the direct sum of complexes is defined using the notation $\bigoplus S_n^\lambda$, not $\sum S_n^\lambda$.

Comment: Which definition are you asking about?  I'm reading Introduction to Algebraic Topology by Rotman and the $S_n(X)$ definition is given in that book.  Regardless of the notation though, do I have the right idea with the direct sum of complexes being an external direct product?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notation used in your definition of "direct sum" is quite nonstandard.  As you say, normally a notation like $\sum_{\lambda\in I} A^\lambda$ is only meaningful if all the abelian groups $A^\lambda$ are subgroups of a single group $A$, so you can take the sum inside $A$.  Here that notation is being used with a different meaning, which is usually written $\bigoplus_{\lambda\in I} A^\lambda$ instead.  This denotes the subgroup of the product $\prod_{\lambda\in I} A^\lambda$ consisting of elements with only finitely many nonzero coordinates.  We can consider each $A^\lambda$ as a subgroup of $\bigoplus_{\lambda\in I} A^\lambda$, namely the subgroup of elements all of whose coordinates are $0$ except possibly the $\lambda$ coordinate.  Note that then $\bigoplus_{\lambda\in I} A^\lambda$ is the internal sum of these subgroups isomorphic to $A^\lambda$ inside the group $\prod_{\lambda\in I}A^\lambda$.